# Regex - Replace strings containing only one but repeating char

Tags: java, regex

I want to replaceAll strings like:

```
"aaaa"
"zzzzzzz"
"----------"
"TTTTTT"
"...."
```

String contains only one char, but > 3 times.

I use Java. I can replace a specific char (like "a") with more than 3 times, but don't know how to do this with any char:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^[a]{4,}$", "");
```

Any idea? If this can't be done in regex, how would you do it?

Comment: Any char? Use `"(?s)^(.)\\1{3,}$"`.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! :-)
Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any char can be matched with `.` and `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier.

To check if it is the same, we can capture the first character and use a backreference to match the same text, and a limiting quantifier `{3,}` to check for at least 3 occurrences of the same substring.

See a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/lK6qB5/1) and [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ClOpRB):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("aaaa", "zzzzzzz", "----------", "TTTTTT", "....");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println("\"" + str.replaceAll("(?s)^(.)\\1{3,}$", "") + "\"");
```